# Hide Away Technical Abstraction of an Object from Users without needing Static Rules

Tags: object-oriented-design, client-side, dynamic

I'm an owner of some Product, where I have different clients who use that product, and the attributes of that product alter the experience that my clients have on my page.

For an example, lets say that clients have a key called "product1" and that would yield a "Product" object with values

```
Product: 
{
    "id": product1,
    "someCrazyTechincalAttribute": 12.50,
    "someOtherCrazyTechnicalAttribute: 100

}
```

So we have a Web UI that will allow clients to alter their product. However, we do not want to expose our clients to all of these attributes because they would not make any sense at all to them. Additionally, a combination of technical attributes may culminate in a single user experience. For example, if a client were to want their product to have a red color, both of those crazy technical attributes would have to be affected. We want to hide away the technical abstraction from our clients by not exposing the technical details of our product.

I know that we could have static rules in the UI that could do the mapping for us. However, we dont think that adding static rules would allow Product owners an easy time to add attributes.

Is there a good Software Engineering method to approach a problem like this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, your question is about the mapping between technical attributes in model objects and non-technical attributes in the object's view:
[image]

So instead of having a direct mapping between attributes in the model and attributes in the view, you could use a mapping object on the client side, which will take care of this mapping. The view would interact with the mapping object, and the latter will interact with the controller, the presenter and the model.

With such a logic, you could use dynamic mapping rules:

- table controlled mapping (e.g. combining technical Product attributes with table values to get the user attributes or vice-versa.
- formula based mapping (e.g. calculating the user attributes from the product attributes)
- or rule based mapping (e.g. applying a combination of transformation rules).

If you use anything else than table mapping, use a [rule engine](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/RulesEngine.html).  This should better be implemented in an OO fashion on the server side: you could implement rules as classes and derive new classes if the rules are complex and require coding.

Answer (score 0):

A single ui feature may require multiple different attribute settings.

As you are realizing, we want to separate feature from implementation.

As with other aspects of coding we want to provide a domain relevant abstraction whose implementation is encapsulated or hidden.

I would suggest manifesting the appropriate feature abstractions that the ui can use to communicate with the back end and putting the mapping of the features to internal attributes in the back end.